# What happened to Firelord Ozai's supporters/followers after the Hundred Year War?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

During Firelord Ozai's reign as Firelord he had many people who went against him who resided within the Water Tribes and the Earth Kingdom and many of the colonies that resided everywhere. It is likely that Ozai would have had loyal servants and many supporters who went with his regime to make the Fire Nation "Superior".

So what happened to them after Prince Zuko became Firelord when the Hundred Year War was over? Is there any evidence to say that he did/didn't have supporters?

Answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5):

In the after years, the comics don't show any kind of rebellion or disturbance related to Ozai.

However, after his attempt to remove the Fire Nation colonies from the Earth Kingdom, Zuko was haunted by criticism from some subjects about him being a weaker Fire Lord than Ozai (in the sense of decision-making). It sort of looks like some subjects still prefer Ozai, but they are a minority and can't do much about this.

In short, no, the comics haven't revealed any particular Fire Nation opposition against their new ruler.

Answer (score 2):

After the show ended, comics were released. In one of the comics there was **'The New Ozai Society'** that didn't want Zuko on the throne.

> This can be read in the comics *'Smoke and Shadow'*. Mai's dad led the society pretty much under the control of Azula. Azula's plan wasn't to have her on the throne, but control Zuko, since he was firelord.  There was also the **'Safe Nation Society'**.